# d3.js - updating fill color for path works with string array, but not with json data

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3.js for a project that involves an interactive map.

For testing, I'd just like to fire a function that changes the fill value for a selection of paths (these represent room outlines).

The paths are already drawn on the canvas.

The path ID value comes from another system.

I have JSON data that I wish to use to join on the paths to update their fill color. The join is based on a key value based on the .attr("id") of the path which will equal a same key value on the incoming json data.

When I fire off my function with a simple test array of strings that is local in the file, it works as expected and updates the fill color of the test group of 4 or 5 paths.

However, when I attempt to use my JSON data, I cannot get the paths to update.

The test array that works is just strings:

```
  var handleColorLink = [
    ["125E0", "red"],
    ["BC5AC", "orange"],
    ["BC417", "red"],
    ["B13D9", "orange"] 
    ];
```

The JSON data looks like:

```
    [{"handle":"BC5AD","mycolor":"blue"},  
  {"handle":"125F6","mycolor":"blue"},  
  {"handle":"171A7","mycolor":"blue"},
{"handle":"17235","mycolor":"blue"},
{"handle":"17236","mycolor":"blue"}]
```

My hunch is that there is no match found on the JSON side key (handle).

code:

```js
function TestFunction() { 

d3.json("http://myjsonURL", function(data) {
 
 d3.selectAll("path")
        .datum(function(d) { return [d3.select(this).attr("id")]; })
  .data(data, function(d) { return d.handle; }) //doesnt work
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d.mycolor; }); //doesnt work
  //.data(handleColorLink, function(d) { return d[0]; }) //works on string array
  //.style("fill", function(d) { return d[1]; });          //works

});
}//end testfunction
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: probably because you filter the data by return d.handle, so you only have access to the handle not the whole data object

Comment: This `.datum(function(d) { return [d3.select(this).attr("id")]; }).data(data, function(d) { return d.handle; })` is extremely odd syntax.  What are you hoping to accomplish?  How are you generating the path's `d` attribute?

Comment: The path is already created. The data for creating the path (d value, id value, etc.) comes in a separate data stream. I want the paths (representing a floor plan) loaded and then I want to be able to change the fill color of a few, named paths. I got the datum example from somewhere online. I have no idea what is 'odd' for d3, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'think outside the box' solution could be, since you know the test array works with your method, just transforming the JSON data into the same structure as your test array. Like this:

```
data = data.map(function(item) { return [item.handle, item.mycolor]; });
```

Then just use it as you are already doing in your d3.js code.

Just an idea ;)

Comment: This worked! I would really like to know how to access the JSON values directly instead of having to use map in this case, though. thanks so much for your input.